# On the fly compression of read- and writeable folder (like Windows EFS)?

Tags: linux, files, aix, compression

Is there a possibility to compress the contents of a directory in Unix (especially AIX) on the fly, while still being able to read and write in the directory? Like the Windows EFS encryption does?

Comment: see also [Whatever happened to compressed read/write filesystems?](https://superuser.com/questions/448436/whatever-happened-to-compressed-read-write-filesystems)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. If you can choose the filesystem of the system, then just use Btrfs filesystem and enable compression for the required directories by using chattr:

```
chattr +c /myfolder
```

If choosing the filesystem is not an option, then look into fusecompress https://github.com/tex/fusecompress

**Edit: AIX specific** solution would be to use JFS1 filesystem with compression which would compress the whole filesystem or use fusecompress mentioned above which works on AIX

Comment: OP asked especially about AIX, probably best not to suggest Linux-only answers (like btrfs). I think AIX has a FUSE port, though.